# KSH: define a variable in for loop with the loop counter (syntax issue)

Tags: shell, for-loop, syntax, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
today=$(date "+%b %e")
homedir=/home/

for dir in jim bob joe; do
    rootfiles_today_[$dir]=$(ssh hostname "ls -lrt $homedir$dir" | grep root | grep "$today")
    printf "\n root owns the following files in $dir "
    printf "\n\tSize\tDate\tTime\tFile Name\n\n"
    printf "$rootfiles_today_[dir]" | awk '{printf "\t" $5 "\t" $6 " " $7 "\t" $8 "\t" $9 "\n"}'
done
```

When I try this, the output gives me

rootfiles_today_jim=: not found

as if the variable name is keeping hold of the = instead of using it to define the variable.  I can't get past this part, each variation involving quotes, [], {}, set -A, eval, (ksh88 does not have define) that i can think of either doesn't work and stops the script, or gives the same above.

How can I properly define the (dynamic? iterative? I don't know the correct term) variable name or persuade it to let the = do its job?

Secondarily, please confirm my way to call the variable once defined is going to be `${rootfiles_today_[dir]}` inside the loop?  What about after the loop is over, if I want to add more to the script and have these 3 vars i can call by name, I will have to either call by their specific full name or `echo $@ | grep word` to call a specific one, or (I am fumbling this question, I know there are many ways to do almost anything) is there another way to call one or all of them iteratively if needed in a subsequent loop?  This is more of a secondary ask, the main issue is getting a useful variable defined.

All of this is simpler in Bash and newer shells, my main stumbling blocks tend to be things that are different or limited in ksh.

Comment: Note, your shebang line is broken: use `#!/bin/ksh` -- "shebang" == "hash+bang"

Comment: ha! thanks. it's been a long day.

Comment: I just noticed: ksh88 -- does that even have arrays? Associative arrays?

Comment: Pretty sure associative array were not supported by ksh88. You would need ksh93 for that.

Comment: is the associative array a reference to the variable name i am trying to accomplish, or antoher part?

if i make a case for $dir i can define each variable 'statically' and the rest of it works, but i was hopeful i could accomplish this as it would be helpful in later parts of what I plan.

Comment: I found a ksh88 man page [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/ksh88-1.html), and it says about "Parameter Substitution": The shell supports a one-dimensional array facility. An element of an array variable is referenced by a subscript. A subscript is denoted by a [, followed by an **_arithmetic expression_**, followed by a ]. You need to adapt to your ksh version.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks for the link i am reading through it to see if i can adapt it to my needs. for now, the case is working as i need it to, but i would like to be able to utilize this generally here and in other parts of my scripting.